# Querying child node fields in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, graphql-compose

I have the following GraphQL schema, which defines 3 types: a `CondaPackage` which hasmany `CondaVersion`, which hasmany `CondaExecutable`. I want to be able to query a `CondaVersion` and ask "how many `CondaExecutable`s do you own which succeeded my analysis". Currently I've written a `succeededExeCount` and `allExeCount` which resolve this field by loading all children and manually counting the number of children that succeeded.

```js
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions: { createTypes }, schema }) => {
  createTypes([
    schema.buildObjectType({
      name: "CondaPackage",
      fields: {
        succeededExeCount: {
          type: "Int!",
          resolve(source, args, context){
              // TODO
          }
        },
        allExeCount: {
          type: "Int!",
          resolve(source, args, context){
              // TODO
          }
        }
      },
      interfaces: ["Node"]
    }),
    schema.buildObjectType({
      name: "CondaVersion",
      fields: {
        succeededExeCount: {
          type: "Float!",
          resolve(source, args, context){
            const children = context.nodeModel.getNodesByIds({
              ids: source.children,
              type: "CondaExecutable"
            })
            return children.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.fields.succeeded, 0)
          }
        },
        allExeCount: {
          type: "Int!",
          resolve(source, args, context){
            return source.children.length;
          }
        }
      },
      interfaces: ["Node"]
    }),
    schema.buildObjectType({
      name: "CondaExecutable",
      fields: {
        succeeded: {
          type: "Boolean!",
          resolve(source, args, context, info) {
            return source.fields.succeeded || false;
          }
        },
      },
      interfaces: ["Node"]
    })
  ])
}
```

My first problem is that this seems incredibly inefficient. For each `CondaVersion` I'm running a separate query for its children, which is a classic N+1 query problem. Is there a way to tell Gatsby/GraphQL to simply "join" the two tables like I would using SQL to avoid this?

My second problem is that I now need to count the number of succeeding children from the top level type: `CondaPackage`. I want to ask "how many `CondaExecutable`s do your child `CondaVersion`s own which succeeded my analysis". Again, in SQL this would be easy because I would just `JOIN` the 3 types. However, the only way I can currently do this is by using `getNodesByIds` for each child, and then for each child's child, which is `n*m*o` runtime, which is terrifying. I would like to run a GraphQL query as part of the field resolution which lets me grab the `succeededExeCount` from each child. However, Gatsby's [`runQuery`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-model/#runQuery) seems to return nodes without including derived fields, and it won't let me select additional fields to return. How can I access fields on a node's child's child in Gatsby?

Comment: Where does your data come from? I'm pretty certain that you *can* just use SQL directly, nothing forces you to go through the `nodeModel`.

Comment: You mean GraphQL? There is no SQL interface. Even then, how? Gatsby doesn't expose utility functions as imports, they're generally passed as arguments to your custom functions. There is a `runQuery` method, but as I said it doesn't actually let you run raw GraphQL. The gatsby API methods [are listed here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/api-reference/)

Comment: I don't believe a custom plugin can do anything that I can't do in my application code, believe me I've looked online. Your link doesn't help at all, I don't need to create nodes, I need to be able to query them inside a field resolver.

Comment: internally it's a redux store then no tables inside, no joins ... why do you expect it will fix your api missings better, more efficiently? ... during node creation you can prepare this info (summary/stats) earlier

Comment: Okay, ignoring the efficiency question, the main problem is simply that I don't know how to query my derived fields from the parent, since they're not returned by `getNodesByIds`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Here's the response from a Gatsby maintainer regarding the workaround:

> Gatsby has an internal mechanism to filter/sort by fields with custom resolvers. We call it materialization. [...] The problem is that **this is not a public API**. This is a sort of implementation detail that may change someday and that's why it is not documented.

See the [full thread here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/25945#issuecomment-662899027).

**Original Answer**

Here's a little 'secret' (not mentioned anywhere in the docs at the time of writing):

When you use `runQuery`, Gatsby will try to resolve derived fields... but only if that field is passed to the query's options (filter, sort, group, distinct).

For example, in `CondaVersion`, instead of accessing children nodes and look up `fields.succeeded`, you can do this:

```js
const succeededNodes = await context.nodeModel.runQuery({
  type: "CondaExecutable",
  query: { filter: { succeeded: { eq: true } } }
})
```

Same thing for `CondaPackage`. You might try to do this

```js
const versionNodes = await context.nodeModel.runQuery({
  type: "CondaVersion",
  query: {}
})

return versionNodes.reduce((acc, nodes) => acc + node.succeededExeCount, 0) // Error
```

You'll probably find that `succeededExeCount` is `undefined`.

The trick is to do this:

```js
const versionNodes = await context.nodeModel.runQuery({
  type: "CondaVersion",
- query: {}
+ query: { filter: { succeededExeCount: { gte: 0 } } }
})
```

It's counter intuitive, because you'd think Gatsby would just resolve all resolvable fields on a type. Instead it only resolves fields that is 'used'. So to get around this, we add a filter that supposedly does nothing.

But that's not all yet, `node.succeededExeCount` is still `undefined`.

The resolved data (`succeededExeCount`) is not directly stored on the node itself, but in `node.__gatsby_resolved` [source](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/d842f8c27c0c65d3c6d6a1113bfe12596f93c13c/packages/gatsby/src/schema/node-model.js#L387). We'll have to access it there instead.

```js
const versionNodes = await context.nodeModel.runQuery({
  type: "CondaVersion",
  query: { filter: { succeededExeCount: { gte: 0 } } }
})

return versionNodes.reduce((acc, node) => acc + node.__gatsby_resolved.succeededExeCount, 0)
```

Give it a try & let me know if that works.

PS: I notice that you probably use `createNodeField` (in `CondaExec`'s `node.fields.succeeded`?) `createTypes` is also accessible in `exports.sourceNodes`, so you might be able to add this `succeeded` field directly.

Comment: I'll have to give this a try, but I think this is exactly the answer I need.

Comment: I would also like to point out this answer I got when I asked this question on GitHub: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/25945#issuecomment-662899027. Which ultimately comes to the same conclusion as this answer, ie don't use derived fields unless you have to, and if you do have to, pass in the field of interest to the query.

Comment: Thanks @Migwell, that sheds a light on this hidden mechanism. I'll add the maintainer's note to the answer.